# Angular 'map' operators can't trigger my subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I used a single HTTP interceptor to solve some common responses.
When response returns { success:true, data: 'xxx' }, I only want pass 'data' field to subscription which is 'xxx'.
When I used the 'tap' operator, my subscription could be triggered. But the data subscription got was '{ success : true, data: 'xxx' }'.
So I decided to use the 'map' operator, but the subscription couldn't be triggered.
My angular's version was 10.0.4 and the version of rxjs was 6.5.5.
Code as below, this is my http interceptor:

```
import { Code } from '../../../code.enum.js';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      filter((res) => {
        return res.type !== 0;
      }),
      map((res: HttpResponse<{ msg; success; data; code }>) => {
        console.log('[AppInterceptor.intercept.tap] res: %o', res);
        const { msg, success, data, code } = res.body;
        if (success) {
          console.log('[AppInterceptor.intercept.tap] data: %o', data);
          return data;
        }
        if (code === Code.needLogin) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        }
        console.log(msg);
        throw new Error(msg);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

here is my login component:

```
import { AppService } from './../app.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  login() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      const { username, password } = this.loginForm.value;
      this.appService.login(username, password).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('[LoginComponent.login] res: %o', res);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      });
      return;
    }
    console.log('nonononono');
  }
}
```

and this is app service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(username, password) {
    return this.httpClient.post('/login', {
      username,
      password,
    });
  }

}
```

console log ,as you can see, code 'console.log('[LoginComponent.login] res: %o', res)' has never being run, and the response data of login API is { success: true } :
[image]

Comment: Could you console.log your body content??

Comment: Sorry, what is body content? I post in the last section, console.log only shows messages in the interceptor, not login component. @AlejandroCamba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interceptor is expecting to return an Observable<HttpEvent>, anything other than that wouldn't go through, remember that even though it is being intercepted it should still remain an Http event when it gets to your component.

You could do something like:

```
    const evt = { ...res };
    evt.body = evt.body["data"];
    return evt;
```

to return an event containing only the "data" property.